# woocommerce giving loop redirect if user not loggedin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i'm working on WP WooCommerce, but now its cause a issue, like if user not logged-in or didn't have any product in cart then https://www.asura.com/my-account/ creates a Loop Redirect.

I tried with is_ssl() but still unable to fix it out, also i tired with .htaccess rules but i'm not good in .htaccess rules so it's not working for me ...

but if a user is logged-in or have at-least one product in cart he can access that page ... now i'm unable to figure it out the source of the problem.

Please Help me out ...

Answer (score 0):

I have same proble with u . i have fixed it

U nedd to create a new page with my account shortcode from Woocomerce . and removed the recent page contains Woocomerce my account shortcode .

Then Set the page my account on Woocomerce setting . With the Newest

Comment: Can you try to word your answer better? It is unclear what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

At First make sure your my account page have this shortcode `[woocommerce_my_account]`

After that navigate to **WooCommerce > Settings > Pages** ( for WooCommerce 2.2 or earlier version ) or **WooCommerce > Settings > Accounts** ( for WooCommerce 2.3 ) 
and make sure that you choose same page for "My Account Page" from the drop-down next to it.